# full width :hover background for nested lists?

Tags: html, css

The html snipped below renders a nested list of elements. On hover (mouse over) the elements background color changes. But a space is left uncolored on the left (due to the indentation).

How would I get that space to be colored as well?

I tried to add `absolute` positioned elements to the `li` elements with `left:0`. But those partially hide the content of the `li` elements :/

```css
ul { 
  list-style: none; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin:0 
}
li { 
  margin:0;
  padding: 0; 
  padding-left: 20px; 
}
li > div:hover { 
  background-color: #eee
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
  <ul>
    <li><div>Root</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div>A</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>AA</div></li>
            <li><div>AB</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div>B</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>BA</div></li>
            <li><div>BB</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use this CSS to make your div's fill the indents so that space is not left uncoloured on the :hover effect, then set the overflow to hidden on the parent wrapper.

```
li div{
  padding-left: 100%;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

This way it is generic so that you can have as many sub `<ul>` and `<li>` tags as you need. Here is a link to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToddNewent/fb5f1fao/) with a working example.

Answer (score 12):

Add the padding to the divs instead of the `<li>`:

```
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin:0 }
li { margin:0; padding: 0;}
li > div:hover { background-color: #eee}
li div{padding-left:20px}
li li div{padding-left:40px}
li li li div{padding-left:60px}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/MKK8v/

By setting it on the list item, you end up padding all the child list items as well. If you can alter your markup, I think there are better ways though.

Comment: Can be made generic (plus support older browsers) by using some JS code. :)

Answer (score 1):

There problem occurs,because you have applied `padding-left: 20px;`,So that Hover will not applied to that part which contains `20px padding` from left.

As my suggestion,For proper html structure & css,You have to assign **class** or **id** name to `<li>` & `<div>` element,due to that you can easily detect problem & get powerful structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove padding-left from li element and use jquery to add padding-left to div like this:

```
$("li>div").each(function(i, div){
              var $li = $(div).parent();
              var parentCount= $li.parents("li").length;
              var padding = parentCount*20;
              $(div).css("paddingLeft", padding + "px");
            });
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/deIjgNi6dGprqpnFpzSI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way here would be to put the padding and hover background on your `div` elements. It puts a nasty hard limit on your tree nesting levels, as you have to write as many CSS rules as you have levels but... there's likely a horizontal limit for your content width anyways.

```
ul, li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul div:hover {
    background: #eee;
}

ul ul div { padding-left: 20px; }
ul ul ul div { padding-left: 40px; }
ul ul ul ul div { padding-left: 60px; }
/* et cetera*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using jQuery.

I have used an invisible div which positions itself on the `li` being hovered and fills the whole width

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('li > div').hover(function(event) {

      $("div#liSelect").show();
      $("div#liSelect").css('height', $(this).height() + "px");
      $("div#liSelect").css('top', $(this).position().top + "px");
      event.stopPropagation();
    },
    function() {
      $('div#liSelect').hide();
    });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative">
  <div id='liSelect' style='display:none;width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;left:0px;opacity:0.3;background-color:#555;pointer-events:none;'></div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div>Root</div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div>A</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>AA</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>AB</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div>B</div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div>BA</div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div>BB</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: People have very less time in their lives to comment whats wrong instead of just clickin the down arrow and navigatin away just like that.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nicer with CSS, but using jQuery you could:

Add padding to the `div` depending on level.

```
$('li').each((i, el) => {
   $(el).children('div').css('padding-left', 30 * $(el).parents('ul').length)
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ydr6b6z/

Answer (score 0):

Please use this CSS code instead of your code.

```
ul { 
    list-style: none; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin:0 
}

li > div:hover { 
    background-color: #eee
}

li div { 
    padding-left: 20px; 
}

li li div { 
    padding-left: 40px; 
}

li li li div { 
    padding-left: 60px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to find a generic solution I tried with [CSS Counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). Unfortunately it seems that counters can only be used in `content` properties.

Maybe someone can figure out how to use the counter to get the corresponding `padding-left`...

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  counter-increment: level;
}

ul:after {
  content: "";
  counter-increment: level -1;
}

li div:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li div {
  padding-left: calc(20px * counter(level));
}

li div:before { /* Just for debugging purposes */
  color: #bbb;
  content: counter(level)" ";
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative">
  <ul>
    <li><div>Root</div>
      <ul>
        <li><div>A</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>AA</div></li>
            <li><div>AB</div></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div>B</div>
          <ul>
            <li><div>BA</div></li>
            <li><div>BB</div></li>
            <li><div>BC</div>
              <ul>
                <li><div>BCA</div></li>
                <li><div>BCB</div></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><div>C</div></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```